# Even / Odd list comps two ways

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to make the same list two different ways (just for practice)

INPUT: list of ints
OUTPUT: list of strings

1st way: replacing ints with 'even' or 'odd' depending on whether the   elements in example list are even or odd.

2nd way: use map to do the same

```
Example:
>>> even_odd([6, 4, 1, 3, 8, 5])
['even', 'even', 'odd', 'odd', 'even', 'odd']
```

I know it's possible, but I keep running into either SyntaxError or TypeError (generator and int when attempting % division on items in list)

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Yeah, how are we supposed to explain what's wrong with `even_odd` if you don't show us how you coded it?

Comment: `return ["odd" if i%2 else "even" for i in l]` will cut it. I would avoid `map` for that one, since you'd need a lambda.

Comment: Show your code so we can see where your mistake is being made.

Comment: Please post your code as well and then we can try to help

Comment: I've tried about 13 iterations of the code to no avail. I figured posting all 13 variations of the same problem would be more cumbersome to all than seeing how others would do it.

Comment: @shash678 it worked perfectly. I think it was adding `list` to the front that saved it from being the <generator> type.

Comment: Typically asking for code without showing your own attempt is not very well received. In this case you got an answer, which overall in the community is frowned upon when a question is clearly not on-topic and typically would be closed quite quickly. The next time please put together a more code-centric [MCVE].

Comment: Furthermore, there is a *very* good reason you were getting that <generator> type. For something like this, it is well worth your time to look up why that was happening in the documentation. Your code was most likely working all this time and if you showed some of your code, you probably would have had a faster answer and an explanation that would have given you that much more knowledge as to what your mistake was.

Comment: @idjaw hmm. I just began learning a few months back - have seen plenty of  helpful questions **AND** answers that don't include code. Didn't realize this was a __thing__. Furthermore, how would you define this question about using map in a list comps to be **not** on topic?   

My mistake was not being able to figure out how to get the result, so the answer below was exactly what I needed to understand.

Comment: @be-ns Yes, I know what you are referring to. The site has gone through different sets of what could be considered on-topic/off-topic, and you will find a slew of questions that are dated several years ago that would be considered off-topic now. Typically, the common trend of questions coming along here that ask for code without showing code does not get received very warmly because they *usually* are homework grabs. Not necessarily saying this is the case for you. But this is how a lot of questions will be received.

Comment: @be-ns FWIW, my comments were in no way a personal attack to you. Just an explanation of how typically non-code questions can be received here. Here is some information: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There are a bunch of links provided there to follow. Furthermore, the most important one would be putting together the [MCVE].

Comment: @idjaw Ok, this is helpful. Like I said, I've only been learning python / on here for a short period of time... I'll try to have more precise questions with code from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def even_odd(L):
  return ['even' if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd' for x in L]
```

Using this great [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) from [pythons official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) you can figure out how to convert the above to a map function:

```
def even_odd2(L):
  return list(map(lambda x: 'even' if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd', L))
```

**Example Usage:**

```
print(even_odd([6, 4, 1, 3, 8, 5]))
print(even_odd2([6, 4, 1, 3, 8, 5]))
```

**Output:**

```
['even', 'even', 'odd', 'odd', 'even', 'odd']
['even', 'even', 'odd', 'odd', 'even', 'odd']
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/G2tQ/1)